# Controller only recognises first selected option

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am passing a multiple selected item list from my view to the controller via a submitted form, but when I declare it as a string paramenter in my controller actionlink, it only ever gives me the first selected value, I was hoping for a list of the selected items.  What should the parameter be in my controller actionlink?  Please see code below.  Thanks for your help as always.

View

```
<select name="listoflocations" class="selectlist" multiple />
    foreach (var results in Model)
    {
        <option name="locnumber" value="@results.LOCNUMBER">@results.CLIENTNAME | @results.LPOSTCODE.ToUpper()</option>
    }
```

CONTROLLER

```
public ActionResult Complete(string listoflocations)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list as parameter in your action:

```
public ActionResult Complete(IList<string> listoflocations)
{
    ...
}
```